# Use multiple reducers in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 reducers:

```js
const initialState = {
    data:[],
};

export const first = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case DATA: {
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload
            }
        }
    }

    return state;
};
```

and second:

```js
const initialState = {
    data2:[],
};

export const second = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case DATA2: {
            return {
                ...state,
                data2: action.payload
            }
        }
    }

    return state;
};
```

I decided tu use `combineReducers` to merge them. Fot this, i used:

```js
const rootReducer =  combineReducers({first, second});
```

My store:

```js
import rootReducer from "./reducer/rootReducer";

export const store = createStore(rootReducer);
console.log(store.getState())
```

When i check the state of the store with `store.getState()`, i get an object something like this:
`{first: {…}, second: {…}}`, 
but i need to use `destructuring` of these 2 objects inside combine reducers.
For this i made:
    `const rootReducer =  combineReducers({...first, ...second});`
but now, i got an emty object, plus this error: `Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.`
**Question**: Why i can't `destructure` the reducers like i wrote above? How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot destructure the reducers like above is because they are functions and not objects

If you carefully look you are creating an object for combineReducers like

```
combineReducers({
   first: (state, action) => {...},
   second: (state, action) => { ...}
})
```

Now `combineReducer` returns you a single function by combining the reducers which you can pass to `createStore`,

You can destructure the individual state post `store.getState()`

```
const {first, second} = store.getState();
const data = {...first, ...second};
```

Comment: i added some code from store where i `createStore`, could you show please for my example how to combine reducers, because i can't understand the idea with functions inside combineReducers, plus how should the createStore looks?

Comment: what should i add inside  `createStore(here);`?

Comment: CreateStore will exactly hook it is at present, you cannot spread your reducers. The only change that will happen is post accessing store.getState()

Comment: so i cant destructure all values in my store?

Comment: You can destrucutre while you access state not while adding it in store. If you want to do that write everything in one reducer instead of having 2 reducers